# I ran an API on Eclipse, but it doesn't work on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I used iFLYTEK's translation API, when I ran it on Eclipse, it works, but it doesn't work in Android Studio, the API returns null.

HttpUtil

```
public static Map<String, Object> doPost2(String url, Map<String, String> header, String body) {
        Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        PrintWriter out = null;
        try {
            URL realUrl = new URL(url);
            URLConnection connection = realUrl.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            for (String key : header.keySet()) {
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty(key, header.get(key));
            }
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            out = new PrintWriter(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            out.print(body);
            out.flush();
            if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK != httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getErrorStream()));
                System.out.println("failed，code：" + httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() + "，message：" + br.readLine());
                return null;
            }
            String responseContentType = httpURLConnection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
            if ("audio/mpeg".equals(responseContentType)) {
                byte[] bytes = toByteArray(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                resultMap.put("Content-Type", "audio/mpeg");
                resultMap.put("sid", httpURLConnection.getHeaderField("sid"));
                resultMap.put("body", bytes);
                return resultMap;
            } else {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                String result = "";
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                resultMap.put("Content-Type", "text/plain");
                resultMap.put("body", result);

                return resultMap;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Main

```
Map<String, Object> resultMap = HttpUtil.doPost2(WebITS_URL, header, body);
```

this is the part that returns null, the url, header and body isn't null, and is already correct. What should I check? Or is there any way to fix this?

I already tried checking the dependencies, and I also tried running it on other device. It still doesn't work.

Comment: How does your url look like? Why didnt you even tell that you are posting data to a webserver? Well i think you do..

Comment: `the API returns null.` Really? Or do you mean that `catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }`?

Comment: I use the api from this site, I only followed the instruction, and modified the demo file a bit. The url is https://its-api-sg.xf-yun.com/v2/its. Thanks, it is from the exception, I forgot to check that.

Comment: Post the url between ticks please as now we dont see the protocol.

Comment: You should tell us value of e.getMessage() and tell us which statement causes the exception. Find out please.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new at this, could you tell me how to Post the url between ticks. And I found out that the error is "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException", so I'll try making a new thread.

Comment: A tick is just a character on your keyboard. So use one left and one right.

Comment: The exceptions were the same, it's NetworkOnMainThreadException. I applied multi threading, and it works.